# Scp Php files into server using gradle

Tags: php, jenkins, gradle, ant, devops

**I want to transfer PHP Files into sever Using gradle .I tried with below script but i dont how to pass username and password**.

```
plugins {
  id 'org.hidetake.ssh' version 'x.y.z'
}

remotes {
  webServer {
    host = '192.168.1.101'
    user = 'jenkins'
    identity = file('id_rsa')
  }
}

task deploy {
  doLast {
    ssh.run {
      session(remotes.webServer) {
        put from: 'example.war', into: '/webapps'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
plugins {
  id 'org.hidetake.ssh' version '2.9.0'  
}
ssh.settings {
knownHosts = allowAnyHosts
}
remotes {
  webServer {
    host = 'ip'
    user = 'username'
    password='password'
  }
}

task deploy {
  doLast {
    ssh.run {
      session(remotes.webServer) {
        put from: 'src', into: '/home/Desktop/Gradle'

      }
    }
  }
```